# How to check against two values in a single IF statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Hi everyone :) english isn't my first language so please excuse any mistakes

my question is how to set two answers for Choice1 in the following code, if i enter G or Google it redirects to google.com and Y or Yahoo it redirects to yahoo.com

```
 var CHOICE1 = prompt("Enter Your Choice Google/Yahoo: ");

    if ( CHOICE1 == 'Google' && 'G' ){
        iimPlay('CODE:'+'SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 100'+'\nURL GOTO=www.google.com');}

    else if ( CHOICE1 == 'Yahoo' && 'Y' ){
        iimPlay('CODE:'+'SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 100'+'\nURL GOTO=www.yahoo.com');}
```

I don't have a great knowledge in javascript/programming. I searched Google and tried some of the suggestions but none have worked.

So, whats wrong in this code, and how can I fix it? and thanks in advance

Comment: you simply need to check for both the values with an `||` operator

Comment: What'd you expect this `CHOICE1 == 'Google' && 'G'` to do ? 1) You cant pass the if statement if choice is `Google` AND `G`. 2) You dont specifiy what `G` must be. Use the or operator `||` for multiple checks. `CHOICE1 == 'Google' || CHOICE1 == 'G'`.

Comment: thnks mate :) it's working  thanks for your valuable reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `|| (logical OR)`. [read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) for logical operators

```js
var CHOICE1 = prompt("Enter Your Choice Google/Yahoo: ");

    if ( CHOICE1 == 'Google' || CHOICE1 == 'G' ){
        iimPlay('CODE:'+'SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 100'+'\nURL GOTO=www.google.com');}

    else if ( CHOICE1 == 'Yahoo' || CHOICE1 == 'Y' ){
        iimPlay('CODE:'+'SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 100'+'\nURL GOTO=www.yahoo.com');}
```

Comment: thnks mate :) it's working  thanks for your valuable reply and have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (CHOICE1 == 'Google' || CHOICE1 == 'G') {
    iimPlay('CODE:'+'SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 100'+'\nURL GOTO=www.google.com');
}

else if (CHOICE1 == 'Yahoo' || CHOICE1 == 'Y') {
    iimPlay('CODE:'+'SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 100'+'\nURL GOTO=www.yahoo.com');
}
```

When using logical operators, read it as it were in English. For example: `||` is **OR**, and `&&` is **AND**. So, if you try to read my answer, it would be: *If `CHOICE1` is equal to 'Google' **or** `CHOICE1` is equal to 'G', then...*

Based on your original solution, it's read as: *If `CHOICE1` is equal to 'Google' **and** 'G', then...*

If you analyze it, you'll probably realize that it's impossible for a value to be 'Google' and 'G' at the same time. Also, just to add, JavaScript evaluates your if condition as such: `if ((CHOICE1 == 'Google') && 'G')`.

Comment: thnks mate :) it's working  thanks for your valuable reply

Answer (score 0):

If there are more and more possible answers, it may be easier to search the value in an array:

```
if (['Google','G'].includes(CHOICE1))
    iimPlay('CODE:'+'SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 100'+'\nURL GOTO=www.google.com');
```

Comment: thnks mate :) it's working  thanks for your valuable reply have a nice day

Comment: is it possible to add more than two values ?? like                                       **`if (['Google','G','G1','G2','G3'].includes(CHOICE1))`**

Comment: @kannan kr yes. Thats what my answer is about